# Docker desktop service not running

Tags: docker, windows-10

I am trying to run Docker in Windows 10, during installation I was getting error regarding server not running so I started server service manually as below

```
Run -> services.msc -> start "server" service
```

After this Docker got installed successfully but once system is restarted I got the error message as below

[image]

I believe this error is again because of server service, I checked the server service and it is disabled, now I am not getting an option to start the server service

[image]

System Config:

- Docker Version: 4.8
- Operating System: Windows 10 Enterprise

**Update**

I am able to start the `server` service by changing the "Startup type" but now I am getting below error

https://user-images.githubusercontent.com/66588814/161082253-86cf1ae6-3795-497c-802f-74bf23685c1e.png

Comment: can you Enable by changing  the startup type?

Comment: @kus I didn't get you, I ran it with administrator right

Comment: you might have tried, in above image,-> Startup type: [Disabled]. You should be able to change this, once enable you can start the service.

Comment: @kus Ohh yes that worked but now I am getting other WSL related error https://user-images.githubusercontent.com/66588814/161082253-86cf1ae6-3795-497c-802f-74bf23685c1e.png

Comment: did you try as suggested on error message itself? There might be permission issue